# Getting a version error in java

Tags: java, runtime-error

Usually the version error in java occurs due to a package being compiled in a higher version and being run on a lower version of java ( this is my understanding, please correct if I am wrong ) but I have the same version of java installed on 2 nodes but still getting a version error when the package is compiled on one of the nodes and run on another node. The jdk used for installation is "jdk-7u17-linux-i586.tar.gz". Both the machines are running  32-bit Linux(Ubuntu) OS.

Any idea why this could be happening ?

Comment: Can you please show us the **exact** error that is shown to you?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Maybe you have more than one JDK installed.

Comment: This kind of errors usually shows up when multiple JREs/JDKs are installed and you are actually running another one. Check `java -version` on both machines and see if you have OpenJDK or GCJ installed.

Comment: Which version do the application servers running use? Maybe configured differently? Maybe shown in the boot log too, before the app is launched.

Answer (score 4):

You can check for multiple installation of JRE/JDK.

> update-java-alternatives -l

- Shows you all the Java versions you have installed.

> java -showversion

- Shows you the java version you are using and help.

> java -version

- Java Version only